# ask if .html() has img element with specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how I can ask if an image with an `#id` exists in `.html()`.

For example:

```
$('#mydiv').find("iframe").contents().find("body").html(findIMGwith#id);
```

The image will be in the body, not somewhere else. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( $('#mydiv').find("iframe").contents().find("body #id").length > 0){
  // image#id exists
} else {
  // image#id doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a parameter into `.html` it sets the HTML.

If the image has an id, why don't you just get it the good ol' fashioned vanilla way?

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document.getElementById(imgId);
```

This method works in IE and older versions as well. No jQuery required.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image using `document.getElementById("id")`. If this is `null` or `undefined`, then that means the image does not exist. Otherwise, it does exist and you can get the HTML via `$("img#id").html()`.